# Error Vector Magnitude: Ref at Origin

Tags: data-analysis

I have a cluster generated by white Gaussian noise in terms of a phase and an amplitude. The center is at the origin and I want to calculate the Error Vector Magnitude of this cluster (equation below).

1) The problem I ran into was that the reference data is almost equal to 0. The equation I am using causes my result to by infinity. How do I calculate EVM if my calculated data reference point is at the origin?

2) I have tried to process the data by adding and normalizing to get an offset. However, the result is expanded about the unit circle. Is there a way to process the data such that the denominator is not (0,0) and also maintain the size the of cluster relative to the data reference point?

[Equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n30gd.png), [Variable details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RmvmR.png) (From comm.evm matlab documentation).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to bug everyone. I thought my question would be more mathematically complex and tickle some brains out there.

1. Convert from polar coordinates to Cartesian.
2. add an offset of 1
3. convert back to polar

Making the cluster offset uniformly relative to the data ref.